# Qt development using correct fonts for host OS

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a project using Qt, the version of Qt and the compiler used is dictated by the client I'm contracted to:

```
Qt Creator 4.4.1
Based on Qt 5.9.2 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
```

I would like to create a forms/dialogs that will always use the correct system font and size according to the host operating system it is running on.

For the application I'm working on the host OS is Windows 10. I've chosen System Font, however the only sizes are 16 and 20 which doesn't look correct.

I want the application and its forms to look like any other application running on the host, not like its been created with non-standard look and feel.

Is there a selection/setup within Qt Creator that will allow me to achieve this?

Comment: Qt usually will look like any other native application by default if you don't override any styles. What is the look you get, and what would you expect? Can you give an example?

Comment: @king_nak, when I start to create a new form and add a label to the form, the label font doesn't match anything like the fonts that appear in other dialogs, the font size is very small.  Its the font size and name I want to obtain.

Comment: How you create the form? Do you change any settings? Where you get the wrong display? In Qt Designer? On your development machine? On the client's machine after deploying? Please provide some more details and if possible source code or screen shots

Comment: @king_nak, I create the form using **Qt Creator**, no settings are changed, drag and drop a label from the tool kit onto the form and the font is tiny.  This is all on the development machine.  The layout of the form and positioning of widgets are all based on the WYSIWYG display, so if its wrong on the development machine it will also be wrong on the client's machines.  There is no source code for this presently, just using the form designer.   When I drag a new label onto the form the default font is [MS Shel DLL 2,8], which is tiny.